# How to detect if MS Runtime or Office is installed on computer on application stratup?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, setup-project, office-interop, microsoft-runtime-library

I have a WinForm program developed in VB.Net with Visual Studio 2005.  The program needs Microsoft Office Runtime installed atleast on the computer to allow the application to run without any errors.

Is their a way to check the computer to see if the minimum of the Runtime or Microsoft Office is installed on the computer?  If either isn't I would like to display a message to the user on the startup of the application that states to atleast go to Microsot's site (I have full link to Runtime Download) and download the runtime for free.

Or is their a way to include the runtime as a component with my install for the application so if it isn't installed on the computer already it will install when the application is installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you more specific details please specify the exact runtime you are interested in. Office has lots of them.

For a launch condition you can try this approach:

- select your setup project in solution explorer
- go to its Launch Conditions Editor
- create a registry search which determines if the runtime is installed or not
- create a new launch condition
- add the registry search property as the condition

This way the installation stops and shows the message you specify if the search doesn't find anything.

Another approach is to include the runtime as a prerequisite:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- right-click it and select Properties context menu
- click Prerequisites button in the property page
- check the prerequisite you want

If the prerequisite you want is not in this list, you will have to [configure it manually](http://setupanddeployment.com/uncategorized/custom-prerequisite-visual-studio-setup-file/).